# In highcharts, how do I get all categories showing with multiple series and xAxis type set to category?

Tags: highcharts

I have a column chart that I am trying to get it to render multiple series with multiple categories.  An because I am configuring the highchart via json I want to avoid having to set the categories in a separate location as the data.  I found that if you set the xAxis.type to 'category' it will look in the series data for the categories.  However, when I do this with multiple series and categories the categories get kinda messed up.  How do I get this working so that all the categories are showing up appropriately?  Pear is twice and Apple does not even appear.

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
  "title": {
    "text": ""
  },
  "chart": {
    "height": 400
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
  },
  "series": [
    {
      "name": "East",
      "type": "column",
      "data": [
        {
          name: 'Apple',
          "y": 98.9
        },
        {
          name: 'Apricot',
          "y": 66.71
        },
        {
          name: 'Cherry',
          "y": 33.77
        },
        {
          name: 'Pear',
          "y": 362.24
        },
        {
          name: 'Orange',
          "y": 48.9
        }
      ],
      "_colorIndex": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "West",
      "type": "column",
      "data": [
        {
          name: 'Peach',
          "y": 348.83
        },
        {
          name: 'Pear',
          "y": 181.78
        },
        {
          name: 'Lemon',
          "y": 760.83
        }
      ],
      "_colorIndex": 1
    }
  ]
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

See fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/vb8zz9ma/3/

Comment: You can set the x value for each data element.  But, if you are doing that you might as well create the categories list.  From the documentation: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.categories   "... if you have multiple series, best practice remains defining the categories array."

Comment: In short, Highcharts lib doesn't match categories in different series and doesn't sort data. Example using `x` indexes for second series (first one may remain as is): http://jsfiddle.net/vb8zz9ma/4/

Comment: @PawełFus I wanted to mark you as the answer, but You did a comment instead. If you could answer it then I could mark it as the answer so otehrs can see how to solve it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highcharts lib doesn't match categories in different series and doesn't sort data. Example using x indexes for second series (first one may remain as is): http://jsfiddle.net/vb8zz9ma/4

Example:

```
"series": [
  {
    "name": "East",
    "type": "column",
    "data": [
      {
        name: 'Apple',
        "y": 98.9
      },
      {
        name: 'Apricot',
        "y": 66.71
      },
      {
        name: 'Cherry',
        "y": 33.77
      },
      {
        name: 'Pear',
        "y": 362.24
      },
      {
        name: 'Orange',
        "y": 48.9
      }
    ],
    "_colorIndex": 0
  },
  {
    "name": "West",
    "type": "column",
    "data": [
      {
        name: 'Peach',
        "y": 348.83,
        x: 5
      },
      {
        name: 'Pear',
        "y": 181.78,
        x: 3
      },
      {
        name: 'Lemon',
        "y": 760.83,
        x: 6
      }
    ],
    "_colorIndex": 1
  }
]
```